# Evitar el redireccionamiento del formulario no funciona

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, mysqli

Hola estaba haciendo un sistema para agregar información a una base de datos con un formulario, `Ajax` y `PHP`.

Los `script` ya los había hecho hace tiempo y el prevenir la dirección funcionaba, ahora que los vuelvo a usar me redirecciona al `script` de `php` en vez de mostrarme la información en la consola.

Estoy usando `JQuery` 3.4.1 y no entiendo que es lo que sucede, he usado `event.preventDefault()` pero aun así sigue redireccionándome. Les agrego una imagen de la redirección a la que me envía.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La respuesta y el id deberían mostrarse en la consola y desplegar una notificación de `Sweet Alert2` dependiendo si se a ejecutado con éxito o no la consulta.

Les dejo los `script` a ver si pueden ayudarme.

**PHP**

```
<?php
include_once 'funciones/funciones.php';
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];


if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') {

  $directorio = "./../public_html/img/portfolio";

  if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
    mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
  }

  $tmp_name = $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['tmp_name'];
  $name = $_FILES["archivo_imagen"]['name'];

  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$directorio/$name")) {
    $imagen_url = $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['name'];
    $imagen_resultado = "Se subió correctamente";
  } else {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => error_get_last()
    );
  }

  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO portfolio (titulo, categoria, descripcion, url_img, fecha, editado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, now(), now())");
    $stmt->bind_param("siss", $titulo, $categoria, $descripcion, $imagen_url);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id_registro = $stmt->insert_id;
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_admin' => $id_registro
      );
    } else {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error',
        'error' => mysqli_error($conn)
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }

  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}

if ($_POST['registro'] == 'actualizar') {
  $id_registro = $_POST['id_registro'];

  $directorio = "./../public_html/img/portfolio";

  if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
    mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
  }

  $tmp_name = $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['tmp_name'];
  $name = $_FILES["archivo_imagen"]['name'];

  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$directorio/$name")) {
    $imagen_url = $_FILES['archivo_imagen']['name'];
    $imagen_resultado = "Se subió correctamente";
  } else {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => error_get_last()
    );
  }

  try {
    if ($_FILES['archivo_imagen']['size'] > 0) {
      // Con imagen
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE portfolio SET titulo = ?, categoria = ?, descripcion = ?, url_img = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_portfolio = ? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("sissi", $titulo, $categoria, $descripcion, $imagen_url, $id_registro);
      $stmt->execute();
    }else {
      // Sin Imagen
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE portfolio SET titulo = ?, categoria = ?, descripcion = ?, editado = NOW() WHERE id_portfolio = ? ");
      $stmt->bind_param("sisi", $titulo, $categoria, $descripcion, $id_registro);
      $stmt->execute();
    }

    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_actualizado' => $stmt->insert_id
      );
    } else {
      $respuesta = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $respuesta = array(
      'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  die(json_encode($respuesta));
}

if ($_POST['registro'] == 'eliminar') {
  $id_borrar = $_POST['id'];
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM portfolio WHERE id_portfolio = ? ');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id_borrar);
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $resultado = array(
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_eliminado' => $id_borrar
      );
    } else {
      $resultado = array(
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    $resultado = array(
      'respuesta' => $e->getMessage()
    );
  }
  die(json_encode($resultado));
}
 ?>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Guarda un registro con subida de archivo
  $('#guardar-registo-archivo').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var datos = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      data: datos,
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var resultado = data;
        if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
          const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            customClass: 'alerta'
          });

            Toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se guardo correctamente'
          })
        } else {
          const Toast = Swal.mixin({
            toast: true,
            position: 'top-end',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 3000,
            customClass: 'alerta'
          });

            Toast.fire({
            type: 'error',
            title: '¡Hubo un error!'
          })
        }
      }
    });
  });

  // Eliminar un registro
  $('.borrar_registro').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var tipo = $(this).attr('data-tipo');

    Swal.fire({
      title: '¿Estás seguro?',
      text: "¡Esta acción no se puede revertir!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
      customClass: 'alerta'
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            'id': id,
            'registro' : 'eliminar'
          },
          url: 'modelo-'+tipo+'.php',
          success:function(data) {
            var resultado = JSON.parse(data);
            if (resultado.respuesta == 'Exito') {
              jQuery('[data-id="'+resultado.id_eliminado+'"]').parents('tr').remove();
              Swal.fire({
                title: '¡Eliminado!',
                text: 'Se eliminó el registro de la base de datos.',
                type: 'success',
                customClass: 'alerta'
              });
            }
          }
        })
       }
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="col s12" role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="guardar-registo-archivo" method="post" action="modelo-portfolio.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
              <input id="titulo" name="titulo" type="text">
              <label for="titulo">Titulo imagen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
              <select id="categoria" name="categoria">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                <?php
                  try {
                    $sql = "SELECT id_categoria, nombre FROM categoria_portfolio";
                    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
                    while ($categoria = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $categoria['id_categoria']; ?>"><?php echo $categoria['nombre']; ?></option>
                <?php }
                  } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                  }
                ?>
              </select>
              <label for="categoria">Materialize Select</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="255"></textarea>
              <label for="descripcion">Descripcion de la imagen</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
              <div class="btn">
                <span>Subir Imagen</span>
                <input type="file" name="archivo_imagen">
              </div>
              <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
              <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-dark btn" id="crear_registro">Crear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

---

**UPDATE:**
En el JS quite parte del código para que no se confunda

Comment: Pasa la línea `event.preventDefault();` hasta el final de la función.

Comment: Ya intente pasarlo hasta el final y siguió ocurriendo

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<form class="col s12" role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="**guardar-registo-archivo**" method="post" action="modelo-portfolio.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

javascript:

```
$('#**guardar-registo**').submit(function(event) {
```

Error en el id.

Cambia:

```
$('#guardar-registo').submit(function(event) {
```

Por:

```
$('#guardar-registo-archivo').on('submit',function(event) {
```

O cambia el id en el formulario:

```
<form class="col s12" role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="guardar-registo-archivo" method="post" action="modelo-portfolio.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

A:

```
<form class="col s12" role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="guardar-registo" method="post" action="modelo-portfolio.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

El valor del id del formulario es diferente al id que usas en el javascript

Comment: de echo antes usaba el on 'submit' y aun asi ocurria lo mismo

Comment: el nombre del id "#guardar-registo" de tu javascript es diferente al que usas en el formulario id="guardar-registo-archivo"

Comment: debajo hay el #guardar-registro-archivo

Comment: Ya edite parte del código de JS, debajo de #guardar-registro estaba el #guardar-registro-archivo así que el problema no es por eso :) perdon

Answer (score 0):

prueba intentando quitar la action de tu formulario ya que al realizar sumbit redirecciona a la ruta que de action

ejemplo:

```
<form url_action="modelo-portfolio.php" class="col s12" role="form" name="guardar-registo" id="guardar-registo-archivo" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

para manejar la ruta de tu archivo maneja otro nombre de atributo, ejemplo url: `$(this).attr('url_action'),`

Comment: Funciono! ya no me redirige pero ahora no se ejecuta

Comment: revisa si esa entrando al evento y si esta obteniendo los datos para ser enviados

Comment: como se revisaba eso disculpa jaja no recuerdo bien perdon

Comment: utiliza la función console.log("mensaje") en parte de tu función o evento para monitoriar e inspecciona en tu navegador, o simplemente agrega alert() en partes de tu función para ver si entra o mostrar un valor

Comment: puse console.log("mensaje") en varias partesde mi funcion y nunca se muestra "mensaje" en la consola

Comment: en tu form agrega onsubmit="return false" ya lo probe y si entra al evento, ejemplo: <form onsubmit="return false"

Comment: si le agrego el onsubmit="return false" ahora no se envía el formulario sea utilizando action o url_action